# How to properly deep copy 2D array of abstract class array in C++ with C style

Tags: c++, c, arrays, polymorphism, abstract-class

I have abstract class `Figure`. Then I have an array of it, and I want to resize it, but not sure how to do it.

```
Figure ** arr; //lets assume it's filled with some data
Figure ** temp = new Figure * [size + 1];
for(int i =0; i < size; ++i)
{
   temp[i] = new Figure(); //it doesn't let me to create object from the abstract class
   temp[i] = arr[i] //if I do this, once I delete arr, I will lose temp as well
}
```

Any help?

Comment: any reason to not using std::vecotr?

Comment: I'd like to do it without vector :D just to see how

Comment: Why do you try to create an instance of an abstract class?

Comment: If I understand it well, you want to make the resize on pointer of pointer of abstract class which are actually points to child?

Comment: Look up the "virtual copy constructor" idiom.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem**

If `Figure` is an abstract class, you can't instantiate it:

```
temp[i] = new Figure();  // ouch:  can't do: strictly forbidden
```

and even if you could, you couldn't copy such a polymorphic class without suffering from [slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing):

```
temp[i] = arr[i];        // arr[i] is a derivate of Figure and might have a different size for example
```

**The solution**

To solve your issue, you must define a virtual `clone()` member function:

```
class Figure {
    ...
    Figure* clone() = 0; 
};
```

You would then implement this function, for example like this:

```
class Square : public Figure {
    ...
    Figure* clone() override {
        return new Square(*this);  
    } 
};
```

You would change your deep copy to to:

```
temp[i] = arr[i].clone();
```

**The improvement**

The risk of returning a freshly allocated clone is to have a memory leak. So 
instead of using raw pointers you could use `shared_ptr<Figure>` or `unique_ptr<Figure>` (not only as return argument of the cloning function but also as element of the array.

By the way, you could also consider changing the array to a `vector`, thus avoiding extra manual memory allocation (and later deletion) of the temp.

Comment: I was thinking of something like this, but can you show me how to do it?

Comment: Also can I do it more efficiently, just by passing pointers, and after all the work to delete the data? How to avoid memory leak if I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to take advantage of the polymorphic behavior the class hierarchy provides and make a `virtual` function to create the copy. For example, `clone` is a commonly named function for this.

#### Example Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}

    virtual Base* clone() const = 0;

    virtual void print() const = 0;
};

class D1 : public Base
{
public:
    virtual D1* clone() const override { return new D1(*this); }

    virtual void print() const override { std::cout << "D1\n"; }
};

class D2 : public Base
{
public:
    virtual D2* clone() const override { return new D2(*this); }

    virtual void print() const override { std::cout << "D2\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> original;
    original.push_back(std::make_unique<D1>());
    original.push_back(std::make_unique<D2>());

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> copy;
    for (const auto& o : original)
    {
        copy.push_back(std::unique_ptr<Base>(o->clone()));
    }

    for (const auto& c : copy)
    {
        c->print();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### Example Output

```
D1
D2
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://ideone.com/XaN3iq)</kbd>

---

All of this can be achieved just the same with C style arrays however this question is tagged with `C++`.

**Note:** Even though the derived classes have a different signature for their respective `clone` functions this is perfectly valid. See [covariant return type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type) for more information.

Comment: Didn't know it's proper to tag abstract class arrays with `C`

Comment: @user5692938 That's not what I was saying. I was justifying my usage of `c++` classes (e.g., `std::vector`, `std::unique_ptr`, etc.).